# Change selected tab in TabView given state change in ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter

I have the following class for holding my state:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

enum ActiveProduct {
  HOME,
  BURGUNDY,
  VIRTUAL
}

class ActiveProductModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ActiveProduct _activeProduct = ActiveProduct.HOME;

  ActiveProduct get value => _activeProduct;

  void set(ActiveProduct newValue) {
    _activeProduct = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Whenever the "ActiveProduct" changes, I want to change the selected tab in a TabView.

Currently I have setup the application like this:

```
class MainScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Text("hello! abc"),
            Text("hello! sdsadsa"),
            Text("hello! 231321"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I change the selected tab in the TabBarView when the ActiveProduct changes?

I have tried wrapping the MainScaffold in a Consumer and set the initialIndex value of DefaultTabController. This didn't work however.

I am using the Provider package for state management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is transforming your `MainScaffold` into a `StatelessWidget` and then, I would not use a `DefaultTabController` but instead I would use a `TabController` and pass it as an argument to the TabBarView.

Then in the `initState` of the `MainScaffoldState`, I would listen on the `ActiveProductModel` and use `tabController.animateTo(yourpage)` whenever something is fired.

I'm not sure that I was very clear in my explanation so here is an example:

```
class MainScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScaffoldState createState() => _MainScaffoldState();
}

class _MainScaffoldState extends State<MainScaffold> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  /// Just for the example
  ActiveProductModel activeProductModel = ActiveProductModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Initiate the tabController
    tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);

    activeProductModel.addListener(() {
       if (mounted)
         /// Here you can do whatever you want, just going to page 2 for the example.
         tabController.animateTo(2);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("hello! abc"),
          Text("hello! sdsadsa"),
          Text("hello! 231321"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```